# Output a spanning tree given a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree

Online resources say: a spanning tree of a directed graph can be found in O(|V|+|E|) time. Note that I'm **not** talking about the minimum spanning tree.

I am looking for an algorithm that can find any one spanning tree given a digraph  D whose edges don't have any weights associated to them.

I can't find any algorithms online. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick any vertex as root, then proceed using a simple [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) or [depth-first Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) to add adjacent vertices to your tree until every vertex has been visited once. Enforce visiting every vertex *exactly once* using a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) (*O(1)* insert and lookup) to check previously visited vertices. That way you will achieve *O(|V| + |E|)* time complexity.

Comment: what if the vertex you chose doesn't lead to a tree. (i.e.) and a different vertex must be chosen for a tree to be constructed. Please recall the question specified the graph is DIRECTED.

Comment: The fact that it is directed does not really matter here, just consider your vertices to be accessible as a parent _and_ as a child of a given node, otherwise many graphs could not even have a spanning tree (_eg._ `{ A -> C, B -> C }` cannot produce any spanning [arborescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborescence_(graph_theory))). Keep in mind that [spanning trees are only defined for undirected graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanning_tree).

Answer (score 1):

The other responses are wrong. A directed graph may or may not have a spanning tree. But it will have a spanning forest.
To find the spanning forest with the minimum number of trees, first perform a topological sort, assume the results are in a stack. Then loop until the stack is empty: pop a node from the stack and construct a spanning tree running a DFS from the popped node, skipping already visited nodes.
And yes, it's O(|V|+|E|).

Comment: This is also implied in michaeldel's comment "as a parent *and* as a child of a given node" since we only have "as a child" normally when it is one directed graph (the example there can't have one `u` as the root of the spanning arborescence).